# Compilation error when creating statement level trigger

Tags: database, database-trigger

I'm trying to use a statement level trigger, not a row-level trigger.

I can't for the life of me figure out how to get this trigger working without compilation errors. Anything super obvious I'm doing wrong? I've tested the select statement to find the count and it works fine.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER bustaxi
AFTER INSERT ON BUS
DECLARE 
var_count NUMBER;
BEGIN

  var_count := (SELECT COUNT(L#)
  FROM (SELECT L# FROM BUS
  INTERSECT
  SELECT L# FROM TAXI));

  IF (var_count > 0) THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-29500, 'Already drives a taxi!');
  END IF;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working. The select statement worked separately but when used like this I needed to use an "INTO" statement. Also, RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR had a number outside of range. Needs to be between -20000 and -20999.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER bustaxi
AFTER INSERT ON BUS
DECLARE 
var_count NUMBER;
BEGIN

  SELECT COUNT(L#) INTO var_count
  FROM (SELECT L# FROM BUS
  INTERSECT
  SELECT L# FROM TAXI);

  IF (var_count > 0) THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'Already drives a taxi!');
  END IF;
END;
/
```